# My gerbils don't know how water bottles work

Tags: behavior, drinking, gerbil

I just got two gerbils yesterday, and they can't seem to use the water bottle. If I tap the end of the nozzle, they will come and drink all the water that drips onto the platform. Then they just sniff around the nozzle, not knowing what else to do. As I write this, one of them is periodically coming to the bottle and searching all around it, and I'm hoping she'll figure it out somehow.

I have no way of knowing if they're dehydrated.

I've tried demonstrating how to use it, but they're too shy to stand there and watch me tap the nozzle. They run and hide if I reach for the bottle.

How do I get them to drink?

Comment: Related post [Can rabbits drink from a bowl of water?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/2354/13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very important to always provide them with water, so you should tap the nozzle yourself to let water collect in the bowl below until they figured it out.

Eventually, they will understand that water is always found near the bottle. When they become less shy and explore their surroundings more, they will probably tap the nozzle by accident. Thant's the moment they learn how the water bottle works. Until then, you must provide the water for them.